# Is it possible in indesign to just write one single line without frame, similar to photoshop?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am new to indesign but is it possible to write a single line to text or a single word without getting a text frame around? As we do in photoshop?

I am trying to write one single letter which can shrink or expand without any boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

No. Not as *live* type. All *live* type must have a text frame.

**However..** you *can* fit the text frame to the type then use the **Free Transform tool** to "shrink or expand" the frame with the type in it all you want. Live type does generally have the glyph bounding area though, which may not align perfectly with the edges of the shapes.

In addition, you *can* convert live type to outlines and then it acts the same as any vector artwork. `Type > Create Outlines`. Of course, then it's no longer live type and can't be easily edited.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I just want to make a one-page resume, do you think indesign is a good option or I should switch to other tools like illustrator?

Comment: @AnkurSehdev It doesn't *really* matter for a single page - either Illustrator or InDesign are great to use. As long as you don't use Photoshop you're well off. Not that Photoshop *can't* be used, it can. However, it's typically not the greatest tool for a text heavy layout such as a resume.